# GET file:///eel.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND. But I downloaded eel through cmd and did the exact same thing what author did

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was writing application which gives the weather, I guess it will work like web page. I was doing the same thing what was doing author and at the end of lesson I got this error, I though it is due to link of jQuery, I changed it and it did not work, then I changed it back.

Html JS code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Weather by Alibek</title>


    <script src="eel.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="image/png" href="weather-icon.png">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

    <input id="location" type="text" placeholder="Write the name of your Country ot City" required="" value="Bukhara, Uzbekistan">

    <button id ="show">Know the weather</button>

    <div id="info ">
        
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        async function display_weather(){
            let place = document.getElementById('location').value;

            let res = await eel.get_weather(place)();
            document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = res;
        }

        jQuery('#show').on('click', function(){
            display_weather();
        });

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is the error

```
GET file:///home/alibek/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B9%20%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB/myfiles/web/eel.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
index.html:27 Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: eel is not defined
```

And when I click button there are more errors

```
    at display_weather (index.html:27)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (index.html:32)
    at HTMLButtonElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js:2)
    at HTMLButtonElement.v.handle (jquery.min.js:2)
```

Please, can someone check it what could happen. Thanks

Comment: Well means eel is not referenced right

Comment: Did you keep eel.js in right spot? https://github.com/samuelhwilliams/Eel

Comment: This has nothing to do with Python. Please only use tags relevant to the question.

Comment: Author said there is should not be any eel file but I have to add the line a code which I did and he did too. But there is no any eel.js files in folder

Comment: But I have installed the eel through cmd

Comment: Can you change your title to something more descriptive of the problem

Comment: The error you got is quite clear: file not found. It means what it says. The file is not there, and it should.

Comment: Where I should get the file, author said I should not add any files, but i have to add line of code